# How to unlock / build the "Imperial March" retail level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I tried to add a new retail level, but it says that no more levels are available at my current progress. The other 10 retail levels have been built, but now it says 10/11 retail levels. The only one left is called "Imperial March" but it has a lock icon and no option to unlock. Has anyone been able to build it yet? Are there conditions that must be satisfied before you can unlock it?

Comment: I think this may be a reward for one of the new Imperial quests.  The update says that finishing them will give rewards including new levels, costumes, bitizens, etc.

Comment: I thought I saw the same thing too, like getting VIPs as rewards, but all 3 new missions have gold as reward, which is really useless to me since I've accumulated more than 25M gold at this point. Maybe if you complete some, some new ones show up, but it's going to take a while given the high requirements (plus I would have to spend more gold just to finish it than what I would earn back).

Comment: Yeah.  I'm basically done with this game.  This update pushed me over the edge.  I don't mind spending the credits, but I've stockpiled tons of Imperial items, and I don't want to spend the time building all new ones.  Too much time for too little pay out!

Comment: David, don't give up on this game yet. Who will answer my questions if you are gone?!?!? Anyway, I was giving myself loony goals just to make myself interested in the game like accumulating 100 million credits to see if I could crash the game (would it? I only got as far as 16 million credits before this latest update came along). Go for the limited edition rewards. And you can build all items on all imperial floors at once without having to wait for the VIP guy so just go crazy! :)

Comment: @Han we'll see. If I get bored, I'll start playing again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Imperial Marches is similar to Panna City Medicines for the Christmas Event and you will unlock it after you accumulate enough medals from building the new Imperial items on the Imperial floors.

If my memory serves me right (please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong), these are the rewards I've unlocked for accumulating service medals:

1. 100 medals - Costume (Rebel pilot for me, not sure if it's the
   same for all)
2. 250 medals - VIP (Level Upgrader)
3. 500 medals - VIP (Recruiting Agent)
4. 975 medals - Bux (10 if I noticed the increase to my total correctly)
5. 1200 medals - 3 Droids: R2-Q5, R4-19, & R5-J2
6. 1725 medals - Imperial Marches

That's all.
[image: Imperial Rewards]

Comment: The next reward after recruiting officer is bux not a new level

Comment: I never considered that. In my excitement, I thought the rectangular shape must mean its a level and never considered that it could be bux. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Will you keep posting the progression here, so people can follow it?

Comment: Yep, this is the definitive answer to the question. This was a pretty cruel challenge - it took me almost 7 days to get all of the medals playing pretty consistently - I don't think you could finish it if you played casually without dumping some bux into it if you didn't get the last update very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

After you unlock recruitment officer it's then bux then r2d2 then imperial march

Comment: Is it R2D2 or a different Astromech droid such as R4?